# mongoose find doesn't return any doc, while compass does

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

**Goal**

Fetching products by category id from mongoDB 'products' collection using mongoose.find

**Excpected and actual results**

All the documents having the matching category should return, in the limit number, but I receive an empty array instead.
I tried to query using mongodb's compass - it worked as expected. I even tried my code to find documents using id(worked), title(worked) and price(didn't work). Can't find the beginning of the problem root.

**Code**

Product schema and model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  thumbnail: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  category: {
    type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
  },
  rating: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
  },
  voters: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
  },
});

.
.
.

const Product = mongoose.model('product', productSchema);

module.exports = { Product, ... };
```

Resolver:

```
products: (_, { limit, category }) => {
      console.log(mongoose.Types.ObjectId('5ec120a9fc13ae248f000004')); // Works fine
      Product.find({ category: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(category) }) // Tried also as a simple string, still not working
        .limit(limit)
        .exec((err, products) => {
          if (err) console.log(err);
          console.log(products);
        });
      if (category) return Product.find({ category }).limit(limit);
      return Product.find({}).limit(limit);
    },
```

Result recorded in the console:

```
5ec120a9fc13ae248f000004
[]
```

Collection 'products' sample:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5ec129e55db26438fcdb9b01"
    },
    "title": "Ecolab - Lime - A - Way 4/4 L",
    "category": "5ec120a9fc13ae248f000004",
    "thumbnail": "https://source.unsplash.com/350x390/?Automotive",
    "price": "236.13",
    "rating": 878210,
    "voters": 2668388
},
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5ec129e55db26438fcdb9b02"
    },
    "title": "Mushrooms - Black, Dried",
    "category": "5ec120a9fc13ae248f000001",
    "thumbnail": "https://source.unsplash.com/350x390/?Sports",
    "price": "439.85",
    "rating": 549879,
    "voters": 2375685
},
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5ec129e55db26438fcdb9b03"
    },
    "title": "Dried Figs",
    "category": "5ec120a9fc13ae248f000004",
    "thumbnail": "https://source.unsplash.com/350x390/?Automotive",
    "price": "202.60",
    "rating": 925701,
    "voters": 2740499
}
```

Comment: It looks like the types of `price` and `category` defined in your schema is inconsistent with what's in the database. From the compass output you see that they're stored as `String`s, while they're defined as `Number` and `ObjectId`

Comment: @thammada As I wrote, I tried also to send the category as simple string to the find function, but still no documents fetched

Comment: Yes, but since your schema is different, it will get converted. You need to either change your schema to match your data, or update your data to match your schema

Comment: You were right! I converted all category fields in the collection to be of ObjectID type and it worked. Thank you @thammada

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: You have to convert the data at the fields `price` and `category`  in your database to `Number` and `ObjectId`

When you are querying data with Mongoose, make sure that the *data types all match*:

1. The *data types* of the field you are **querying** matches with your **schema**

With some operation (like aggregation, where mongoose can not easily infer the types), mongoose will help converting it for you
according to the schema, but not always. It's better to always
convert the values by yourself to avoid surprises like this.

2. The *data types* of the data **stored** in the database actually matches what you specify in your **schema**.

Your schema might have changed, make sure to migrate and convert the data accordingly. Since mongoose converts the values for you sometimes, if the stored data doesn't match the schema, it won't match what you try to query.

From your database output, we can infer that `"price": "236.13"` and `"category": "5ec120a9fc13ae248f000004"` are stored as `Strings` not `Number` and `ObjectId` as supposed to. We can see from `"rating": 878210`,  and `"_id": { "$oid": "5ec129e55db26438fcdb9b01" }` how `Number` and `ObjectId` are represented.